# Element in the convex hull

Tags: analysis

I have a Hilbert space H. I fix elements $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $H$ and define the convex hull $C(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i : a_i \ge 0 \text{ and } a_1 + \dots + a_n = 1\}$. The relative interior of the convex hull is given by $\mathring{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i : a_i > 0 \text{ and } a_1 + \dots + a_n = 1\}$. We have given that $0 \notin \mathring{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. A proof now wants to show that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}_+$
\begin{align*}
d(-\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i , C(x_1,\dots,x_n)) >0.
\end{align*}
(I know that this is trivial, but I am trying to understand the proof given in the notes.)
They suppose $d(-\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i , C(x_1,\dots,x_n)) =0$, hence there exists $ a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $a_i \ge 0$ and $a_1+\dots+a_n = 1$ such that \begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i.
\end{align*}
By this they conclude $0 \in \mathring{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, a contradiction.
I struggle with the final conclusion. From the equality we get 
\begin{align*}
0 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (a_i + \frac{1}{k}) x_i
\end{align*}, 
but we don't have $a_1 + \dots + a_n + \frac{n}{k} = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $- \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i / n \in C(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i / n \in C(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Hence also $ 0 = - \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i /(2 n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i /(2 n) \in C(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and in particular in the relative interior by definition.